# How to get current subcategory in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category

I'm working on product page in which I've to display the current subcategory. I've searched a lot but all I could find is to display all the categories and subcategories. How would I get only a subcategory in which I'm i.e. current subcategory.
I'm using following code-

```
    <?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
      <?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
      <?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
        <?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
         <ul>
           <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
           <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
               <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
            </a>
            <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
           <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
              <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
               <ul>
                 <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                 <li>
                  <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                    <option><?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                    </option>
                  </a>
                 </li>
                 <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
               <?php endif; ?>
               </li>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
         </ul>
     <?php endif; ?>
```

Please some one help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can get subcategories of current category with product count on product page.

```
<?php
$parentCatId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId(); 
$root = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentCatId);
$subCat = explode(',',$root->getChildren()); 

$collection  = $root
             ->getCollection()
             ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
             ->addFieldToFilter("entity_id", array("in", $subCat) );
?>
 <?php foreach($collection as $catname){
$qty = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catname->getId())->getProductCount();?>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="<?php echo $catname->getUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $catname->getName(); ?>(<?php echo $qty; ?>)</a></li>
 <?php   }; ?>
```

Hope, it will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... but It's not working, In fact it's giving me an error "Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on null in /home/retrntrip/public_html/magento/app/design/frontend/arisen/sneezeguard/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml on line 83"

Comment: Replace first line with below code : 


<?php 
 $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
 $_category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
 $parentCatId= $_category->getId();
 $root = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentCatId);
?>


it is working fine for me.